# How to attach click events to iframe content?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have  a scenario where I wanted to load a page on inital load. I found that this would do the trick:

```
<main id="mainContent">
    <iframe id="InitalIframe" src="./Pages/Start/index.html" onload="this.before((this.contentDocument.body||this.contentDocument).children[0]);this.remove()"></iframe>
</main>
```

I have some links in my header which I attach click listners to:

```
(function() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".link").forEach((item) => {
            item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                const url = event.target.dataset["url"];

                getHtmlFile(`./Pages/${url}/`, (data) => {
                    document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = data;
                    executeScripts();
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
})();
```

This worked untill I added a few links inside of the Start/Index.html file which gets renderd via the iframe.

I have these two buttons inside of that html.

```
        <button type="button" class="link refbtn" data-Url="One">
    One
  </button>
        <button type="button" class="link refbtn" data-Url="Two">
    Two
  </button>
```

Since I attached my listners before the iframe has loaded they never get picked up.

But when I waited for the iframe to load:

```
document.getElementById("InitalIframe").onload = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".link").forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const url = event.target.dataset["url"];

            getHtmlFile(`./Pages/${url}/`, (data) => {
                document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = data;
                executeScripts();
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
};
```

the click events did not get attached and I got a weird looking result on the page.

Question is how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with the same:

I made my life easier by listening for document click events. when I found that an element with a certain class was clicked I triggered desierd functions:

```
document.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const classes = event.target.classList;

        if (classes.contains("link")) {
            const url = event.target.dataset["url"];

            app.fetcHtml(`./Pages/${url}/`, (data) => {
                document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = data;
            });
        }

        return false;
    },
    false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to work this with a different approach also. In other words, I had the method `closest()` in pure Javascript finding me the closest event target that is trigerred when I click inside the container. It will always get me the nearest `<a>` element which I clicked when I had wandered throught the clickable div/container area.

```
    let base; // the container for the variable content     
    let dataSet;

    base = document.getElementById(base.id); // target your Iframe in this case. 
    base.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        let selector = '.link'; // any css selector for children
        // find the closest parent of the event target that
        // matches the selector

        let closest = event.target.closest(selector);
        if (closest !== undefined && base.contains(closest)) {
            dataSet= event.target.dataset["url"];

           app.fetcHtml(`./Pages/${url}/`, (data) => {
             document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = data;
            });
        }
    });
```

You can try and see if it works like this also.

Cheers